# How to use JSONModel data in different ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, jsonmodel

I'm using JSONModel in my objective c application. I get all data to my JSONModel in a first abBarController. Then I need get this data in other viewController. I'm trying send this data to the others viewControllers like:

**First ViewController:**

```
@implementation FirstViewController 
...
SecondViewController* infoController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
SecondViewController.model = self.model;//Here send the model with data
[self.navigationController pushViewController:infoController animated:YES];
...
@end
```

**Second ViewController:**

```
@interface SecondViewController :UIViewController{
 MyModel *model;
}

@property MyModel *model;
```

**There is a better form to keep this data model instantiated and get the model data from another viewController without send this in a property?**

Comment: Create shared object in your model class and set JSON object in id object then access it in any ViewController.

Comment: Use a singleton to set or get model data

Answer (score 1):

Create object class

**In .h object class**

```
@interface FirstModel : NSObject{
 }
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *productsArray;
```

**In .m object Class**

```
-(id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {

        _productsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }
    return self;
}
```

**Create another one Object Class**

```
@interface SecondModel : NSObject
@property (nullable,nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

**In TableviewViewcontroller .h file
Import Two Object class and insert the following coding**

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)FirstModel *firstListObject;
```

**In .m file
//cell for rowAt Indexpath**

```
SecondModel *prodObj=_firstListObject.productsArray[indexPath.item];
cell.productNameLabel.text=prodObj.name;
```

You may have access this object class wherever you need…

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton class, create your model property.
In another viewController, you can access your model through instance of singleton. Reference http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/singletons.html

Comment: Could be inefficient use singleton to memory of application??

Comment: Don't worry about memory. They are very small

Answer (score 0):

or you can archive it to the local files using plist or data-base